# Checkbox inside Select dropdown ia not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using bootstrap multiple select in ASP.Net website. I added these links

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
```

and then in my .cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="SecondaryLicenseStatuses">Secondary License Statuses:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9 container">
            <select class="form-control" id="SecondaryLicenseStatuses" data-bind="options: TabLicense.SecondaryLicenseStatuses, selectedOptions: TabLicense.SecondaryLicenseStatusesSelections, optionsText: 'name'" size="5" multiple="multiple"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and in JS file

```
$('#SecondaryLicenseStatuses').multiselect();
```

It says

> TypeError: $(...).multiselect is not a function

Right now my app can select multiple select options by pressing CTRL but I want to make checkboxes with it.
Thanks!

Comment: RTM: http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/ says, quite near the top: "Note that the plugin will work both with version 2.x of the jQuery library as well as with version 1.10.x of the jQuery library." .You're using version 1.9, which is also ancient, there's no reason to use that version. So fix that first, and then also ensure (which isn't clear from your question) that you don't run that code before the page (and all associated JS files and required HTML) have fully loaded (by utilising a jQuery document.ready block)

Comment: Thanks, @ADyson Its Jquery conflict in my project. Now its working but facing an issue when I select multiple options it only shows and saves top option??